# How can I get certain items from a list to another list if certain condition is achieved?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a program that reads a list "vet" of 20 integers. The program has to generate, based on the list, another list "pos"
that contains only the positive values from "vet". From the list "pos", another list "nodup" that contains only
one occurance of each value from "pos" must be generated.

```
    from random import randint
vet = []
pos = []
for i in range (0,20):
    vet.append(randint(-10,10))
print (vet)

for i in pos:
    if vet > 0:
        vet.append(pos)
        pos=pos+1

print(pos)
```

I couldn't really go any past that part, since when I print pos it shows as the list is empty. It was supposed to add the positive values from vet to pos, but why is that not working?

Comment: You need to travers the input list (so `vet` not `pos`), apply the condition to the element (so `i`, not the whole list), then add just the element that passed the condition to the output list (`vet`).

Comment: You already got a couple of answers. But they don't point out the error in your code. Your loop is completely wrong. First, think about the problem in your mind. Ask yourself: what are you trying to solve? What if you had to do it manually? How would go about it? Only when you know what you need to do then start writing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your second loop should be something like this -

```
for i in vet:
    if i > 0:
        pos.append(i)
```

or using list comprehension -

```
pos = [i for i in vet if i > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You find elements that are positive by simple list comprehension, and remove duplicates from that list using `set()`.

```
from random import randint
vet = []

for i in range(20):
    vet.append(randint(-10,10))

pos = [i for i in vet if i > 0]
nodup = list(set(pos))

print(pos)
print(nodup)
```

Output:

```
[8, 2, 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are appending an empty list in a loop to an empty list, thus the result is an empty list again.

Why not just use `numpy` for this`

```
import numpy as np
vet = np.random.randint(-10,10)
pos = vet[vet > 0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really know how what numpy was nor how it even works. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This code will return a random list vet, a list pos of only the positive numbers in vet, and a list nodup with only one of each of the elements in pos.

```
from random import randint
   vet = []
   pos = []   
   for i in range (0,20):
       vet.append(randint(-10,10))
   print (vet)

   for el in vet:
       if el> 0:
           pos.append(el)

   nodup = list(set(pos))
```